# Spyder/Python: Trying to animate but no data appears

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, spyder

I am running matplotlib under Windows 7 using Anaconda and Spyder.  I've drawn various plots.  Now I'm trying to animate.  I have copied about five animation demos from the matplotlib demo source code web site, so there is no doubt that the code is correct.  What usually happens is that the axes are displayed but with no data.  Once I got a wireframe plot to display but it didn't move.

I downloaded Anaconda from its web site about a month ago so presumably I have quite recent versions.  I have found questions in Stack Overflow about similar problems, but no answers.  Looks grim.  I suppose the only answer is to buy another computer running a different operating system.   But I figured I would ask.

I tried

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

No difference.

```
numpy version is 1.15.4
python version is 3.7
spyder version is 3.3.2
```

Code from https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example.html

## """

## Simple animation examples

This example contains two animations. The first is a random walk plot. The
second is an image animation.

"""

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def update_line(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[..., :num])
    return line,

fig1 = plt.figure()

data = np.random.rand(2, 25)
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.title('test')
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, 25, fargs=(data, l),
                                   interval=50, blit=True)

# To save the animation, use the command: line_ani.save('lines.mp4')

fig2 = plt.figure()

x = np.arange(-9, 10)
y = np.arange(-9, 10).reshape(-1, 1)
base = np.hypot(x, y)
ims = []
for add in np.arange(15):
    ims.append((plt.pcolor(x, y, base + add, norm=plt.Normalize(0, 30)),))

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig2, ims, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000,
                                   blit=True)
# To save this second animation with some metadata, use the following command:
# im_ani.save('im.mp4', metadata={'artist':'Guido'})

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please also post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which does not work for you?

Comment: Do not buy a new computer just because you don't see the plots appearing!! There might be several reasons for that, which would all be solvable. First of all, run the examples outside of spyder, i.e. in your normal terminal `python filename.py`. Depending on the outcome one would either need to look deeper or just find the correct settings to make it also work in spyder.

Comment: I ran the file in the Windows 7 command prompt.  I got  ImportError: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.